# Java reference to a method that takes a subclass of another class

Tags: java, functional-programming, extends, consumer

I'm trying to pass a subclass as a parameter to a method.
So far I've not been successfull, and even told it's not possible to do in Java. I want the opinion of stackoverflow, and suggestions to make it work.

Let's assume 'HelloEvent' extends 'Event'...

I have a method :

```
public void addListener(Consumer<? extends Event> consumer) { 
     [...]
}
```

and another method :

```
public void listen(HelloEvent helloEvent) { 
    [...]
}
```

I want to do this :

addListener(this::listen);

In IDEA I have the error 'Cannot resolve method listen'. Of course this happens because 'listen' is not exactly an Event, but rather a subclass.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe a work around?

I've tried having it being a Function or replacing 'extends' with 'super' and it does not work. I've been attempting to fix this problem for a few weeks now.

Comment: Where are you calling `addListener(this::listen);`?

Comment: Anywhere really, in this case we could say addListener and listen are both in the same class and we call addListener in the main method.

Comment: But your main method is `static`, no?  You won't be able to use `this`.

Comment: You're right forget that... Not a static method.

Comment: I actually get a different error, having to do with incompatible types ([see example](https://ideone.com/VjcdPu)), although there's a way to fix it. IDEA gives me this same error too, so your actual code has a problem which you haven't described here. In any case, though, what the answers are saying is probably right: you shouldn't be using `Consumer<? extends Event>` for this in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *can't* just `listen` to any `Event`, only to `HelloEvent`s.

It should probably be `Consumer<? super Event>`, because e.g. [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/869736) .

In that case, you could write

```
addListener(event -> {
  if (event instanceof HelloEvent) {
    listen((HelloEvent) event);
  }
});
```

...but nothing short of that will work, honestly.  You have to check that it's a `HelloEvent` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could do this, you would get a `ClassCastException` when the listener is called. However, if you included the type with `addListener`, you could add logic to filter that.

```
void addListener(Consumer<? super Event> listener) {
    [...]
}
<T extends Event> void addListener(Class<T> type, Consumer<T> listener) {
    addListener(evnt -> {
        if (type.isInstance(evnt))
            listener.accept(evnt);
    });
}
```